# Mocking out legacy libraries

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I'm working on a legacy project that have many external dependencies and classes are so tightly coupled that it's almost impossible to unit test. I know the best way to address this would be doing a major refactor but at the moment we do not have the luxury to do so as the project is virtually 0 tests so we are very concerned about breaking stuffs.

What we are trying to achieve at the moment is to quickly come up with unit / component tests and progressively refactor as we work on the project. For component test I'm thinking to have some kind of wrapper on the existing classes to 'record' the input and output then persist it to a physical file. When we are running tests then it will return output based on the input.

How I'm thinking to achieve that is to store the method name and input parameters as the key and the output as the value. And output will be serialized upon 'record' and deserialized during test.

This approach seems to be able to cater for some cases.. but I foresee there will be a lot of complications later on. Eg: I might face several issues serializing certain objects. And I might also experience difficulties passing object reference from "out" parameters.

So here comes my question. Is there any libraries that does all these things? I would have never considered doing this manually if there was a library for it. By the way I'm using Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing low level unit tests, I would start with tests for the minimum units you can divide now, i.e. possibly just one. You can capture the data input and out using a serialization library which doesn't require the objects be marked as Serializable e.g. Jackson.